# How to use Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor in Unit Test App?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I want to test my DLL for Universal App in Visual Studio 2015 (OS: Windows 10). I find Unit Test App project template in C# category:
[image]

This creates another new App for me, in which, there is a Test class with TestMethod. I tried to run the Test app but I don't think the method is invoked and I don't where to look for the test results.

Anyone have had experience?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a little confusing, since one would naturally expect that "hitting play" to run the Unit Test App would actually run the tests as well.

However, it works similarly to normal DLL-based unit test projects - i.e. you need to invoke the tests from the Test Explorer pane, Test top menu or "Ctrl+R, A" shortcut keychord.  This will deploy and launch the Unit Test App, run the selected tests and then close the Unit Test App when it's finished.  The test results will be shown in the Test Explorer and Output > Tests panes.